# KSQLDB: parent-child join to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ksqldb

I want to create a parent-child relation from the tables I have in KSQLDB to elasticsearch.

In elasticsearch mapping I just define the the join field:

```
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "join_field": {
              "type": "join",
              "relations": {
                "parent": "child"
              }
            },
            ...
```

For parent in ksqldb i just add a "join_field" in the select in ksqldb:

```
  SELECT
    'parent' AS join_field, \
    ...
```

But how do I create the child? Elasticsearch is expecting this format:

```
"join_field": {
    "name": "child", 
    "parent": "1" 
}
```

I use "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector" to push data from ksqldb to elasticsearch.

Comment: I found a way to get the es format.
In ksqldb select i just create a struct like this: STRUCT(name := child, parent := id) AS join_field. But the name and parent is in uppercase by default which doesnt work with ES. backticking name and parent doesnt work either in struct. Any suggestion on how to lowercase struct property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not implemented yet. Hopefully soon.
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/pull/558

While waiting for an official release. It is possible to build the version that support routing with this commit https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/tree/2e25ed8329fad1dc15ba5711e7ed32e0c270dd5d

This config is needed when creating the sink:
"routing.field.name" = "PARENTID"

In KSQLDB select use struct:
STRUCT(`name` := 'child', `parent` := parentid) AS join_field, \